# How i can let users add notes to my posts

Tags: categories, comments

I want to let users add notes to my blog posts, but I want to keep the notes separated from posts. What I mean is to have something like comments.

Is it possible when a user writes a comment that I ask him about the type of his comments? For example is it just a comment or is it something that is not mentioned in the post.
Is there any plugins or sample code to do this?

Note: There are plugins that allow to add footnotes to a post but they do not let users add notes to the post.

Comment: Why not simply use comments and not display them? You could then add a custom meta box listing the comments right at the post.

Comment: Hi, because i want let users speak together about the post. The note is a feature other than comments, to improve what my post is not covered.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of possibilities here:

**1- Giving users the ability to edit posts and add notes.** This is not something you want to do. As it might create many issues for you. However, you can use a [Wiki](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-wiki-plugin/) plugin if you want to pursue this option.

**2- Enabling notes through comments.** This is a better option. You can handle user comments and ask whether he wants to add it as a comment or a note to be added to the post. You need to modify WordPress code and develop your own code as well.

**3- Using footnotes plugin as notes system.** You can use any of the plugins available for footnotes and possibly customize it yo use it a notes system. This [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-footnotes/) seems to be good. It displays the footnote inside the text. You can modify the plugin code to display a note instead of a footnote.